# Is it possible to extract an unsaved word file from hiberfil.sys

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, hibernate, autosave

I had an unsaved word document open before i set my pc to hibernate. After wakeup the word document was gone. There werent any files saved Even though the autosave was on. The question is whether there is a possibility to recover the unsaved file from the hiberfil.sys?

Comment: No; What you want is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Hiberfil.sys is a file the system creates when the computer goes into hibernation mode.

Hiberfil.sys is Windows system file, it does not store office files.

You can try other ways to recover files, please search for AutoRecover files etc.

Be aware that some lost documents may not be recoverable.

More information :

[Recover a lost Word document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/recover-lost-document)